# serve file from virtual directory using nginx

Tags: nginx

How do I serve a static file (let's say `foo.html`) from location `/foo` using NGINX.

I've been trying with [alias](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) but I haven't been successful. Here is what I tried:

```
location /foo {
    alias foo.html;
}
```

Comment: Where is the file `foo.html` located?

Comment: In the `root_dir`

Comment: Do you mean in the root defined by a `root` directive or in the Nginx default root?

Comment: defined by the root directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alias` is similar to a `root` directive and specifies the full path to a file or directory. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location /foo {
    alias /path/to/foo.html;
}
```

---

You could achieve the same behaviour with `try_files`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
root /path/to/root;

location /foo {
    try_files /foo.html =404;
}
```

Comment: With your first example, it works but the MIME type looks like it's not being set correctly - my browser tries to download the file. Additionally, it does not work without specifying the full path for me, even with a `root` directive above. Your second answer *does* work for me, without needing the absolute path. The leading slash is key there.

Comment: Yes, the `alias` needs a full path and the `root` directive is not relevent. But I forgot about the MIME type (which is easily fixed), but the `try_files` solution is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially *rewriting URL* from `/foo` to `/foo.html`, so the `rewrite` is meant exactly for cases like this:

```
rewrite ^/foo$ /foo.html;
```

No need to be scared of a regular expression to be slower - it's not.

Consider that `try_files` approach will have to make `stat` call (check file existence), which makes it slower.